# Date formatting not working for 5/1916

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format two NSString to an NSDate with this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/yyyy"];

NSString *dateString = @"5/1916";
NSString *dateString2 = @"6/1916";

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString2];
```

Guess what:

date is nil and date2 works fine (isn't nil). 
Any idea how this come?

[image]

Edit:
For those who think it's about the string, the next screenshot has the samen problem.
[image]

Comment: both dates work fine at my side, even on simulator and real device; and it presents the correct date.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my question with my result. This is for a real device and a simulator

Comment: Exactly what do you want to get?Please tell me.

Comment: Having a real NSDate object instead of nil. It works for all the dates in 1914 to 1918  except this one

Comment: try cleaning the product and run it again

Comment: Actually your  code gives results like below.Even i tried your code.It works.It does not give any nil result.

Comment: @Francescoverheye, which calendar or timezone are you using?

Answer (score 0):

your code works perfectly fine with following result

```
Printing description of dateString:
05/1916
Printing description of date:
1916-04-30 18:06:40 +0000
```

But issue is that NSDate is something which must have `day, month , year` Just revamp your code to feed dateformatter a correct date.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my question with my result.

Comment: try  @"05/1916" instead of @"5/1916"as itis "MM/yyyy"

Comment: no...  @"MM/yyyy" is the correct notation. Bcoz month 10,11,12 has length 2

Answer (score 0):

in most languages, 5/1916 wouldn't be accepted, but 05/1916 is, since the format is MM/yyyy not M/yyyy. the length of string is mandatory.

hope that helps,
eiran